# Can't import PyQ in Python 3.6 : flat namespace error

Tags: python, python-3.x, kdb, pyq

This is the error message I am getting:

```
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 22 2016, 17:23:13)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pyq import q
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pyq/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>  from . import _k
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pyq/_k.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _b9  
Referenced from: 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pyq/_k.cpython-36m-darwin.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/pyq/_k.cpython-36m-darwin.so
```

My python version is 3.6 and pyq version is 4.0.1.

I installed pyq via pip and Python via regular OS install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyQ is a python interpreter embedded in kdb+ and the pyq module cannot be imported in a stand-alone python.  There are three ways to use pyq:

1. At the q command prompt or in a q script start the line with a `p)` prefix and follow with a python statement. For example,

   ```
   p)from pyq import q
   p)print(q.til(5))
   ```

will print `0 1 2 3 4`.

2. You can place your python code in a file with the `.p` extension and use it as you would a q script: execute from command line

   ```
   $ q foo.p
   ```

or load using the `\l` command.

3. Finally, the `pyq` executable gives a convenient way to run a standard Python REPL either interactively or to execute python programs.  Internally, `pyq` executes `q python.q`, so your code still runs inside a kdb+ instance.  Note that when you run `pyq`, Python REPL takes over and you cannot interact with your kdb+ instance using the standard kdb+ IPC mechanisms.  If you require such communications, use one of the two options described above.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got a solution:  will be able to run [import pyq] when you run your python script with pyq binary. Exactly as you run a regular python script **python xxx.py**, you need instead to run it as **pyq xxx.py**